# How to resolve wingide6 install error?

Tags: debian, dpkg

```
dpkg -i wingide6_6.0.12-1_amd64.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package wingide6.
(Reading database ... 334144 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack wingide6_6.0.12-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking wingide6 (6.0.12-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of wingide6:
 wingide6 depends on libpango1.0-0 (>= 1.18.0); however:
  Package libpango1.0-0 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package wingide6 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for menu (2.1.47+b1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 wingide6
```

Answer (score 0):

The log/messages are telling you what the issue is:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of wingide6:
 wingide6 depends on libpango1.0-0 (>= 1.18.0); however:
  Package libpango1.0-0 is not installed.
```

Specifically it, `dpkg`, cannot install this `wingide6`, because certain prerequisite packages are not installed yet.

So the simple solution is to install whatever package this particular package requires:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libpango
```

Once you have this plus any additional prerequisites installed you should be able to run `dpkg -i wingide6.0.12-1.amd64.deb`.